# ES6: Filter data with case insensitive term

Tags: javascript, filter, ecmascript-6, case-insensitive

This is how I filter some `data` by title value:

```
data.filter(x => x.title.includes(term))
```

So data like

```
Sample one
Sample Two
Bla two
```

will be 'reduced' to

```
Bla two
```

if I'm filtering by `two`.

But I need to get the filtered result

```
Sample Two
Bla two
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use a case-insensitive regular expression:

```
// Note that this assumes that you are certain that `term` contains
// no characters that are treated as special characters by a RegExp.
data.filter(x => new RegExp(term, 'i').test(x.title));
```

A perhaps easier and safer approach is to convert the strings to lowercase and compare:

```
data.filter(x => x.title.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()))
```